# using a .netstandard 1.2 library in 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a .netstandard 1.2 library, which is compatible with .net 4.5.2.
In my library I'm referencing NetStandard.Library 1.6:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.2": { }
    }
}
```

I created a NuGet package from this using dotnet pack and Installed it on my NuGet server. I created a simple console application that targets .NET Framework 4.5.2. I try installing the above NuGet package and I get a huge list of dependencies that it needs to install:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0
System.Collections.4.3.0
System.Collections.Concurrent.4.3.0
... snip
NETStandard.Library.1.6.0
MyPackage.1.0.0
```

I'm assuming the reason I see all these packages is because I depend on the metapackage NETStandard.Library, but is there a way to install this into a full .net framework 4.5.2 project without getting all of those packages added? Should I just add framework net452 to my library even though I don't have any conditional compilation that I need to perform?

Comment: You can interface with DllImport into an executable or dll which doesn't require the dependencies.

Comment: @jdweng that's not really what I'm looking for at all.

Comment: My understanding if we were to use a core nugetpackage in a  full .net (net4.5/46/461) lib is to target that particular framework under `framework{}` in your `project.json` file. So it needs to have `net542` under frameworks section

Comment: Most of them should work as just type forwarders on .NET Framework, which you can safely keep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look carefully the System.Collections package should not contain any DLL's for the .net full framework. I believe instead it just refers to System.Collections as a framework reference. You are still getting the almost empty nuget package because you have a dependency on the NETStandard.Library package, and that defines various api required to implement the library. The extra packages shouldn't actually do anything on the full framework.

If it bothers you (for me it doesn't) You can get around it by being more explicit about your dependencies.

For example:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "frameworks": {
        "net452" : {},
        "netstandard1.2": { 
         "dependencies": {
          "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
         },
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding if we were to use a core nugetpackage in a  full .net (net4.5/451/452/46/461) lib - one needs to target that particular framework under `framework{}` in your `project.json` file.

So it needs to have `net542` under frameworks section. For e.g. The dapper library (ORM) that is compatible with both full .net framework and core has its project.json with all the frameworks it is targeting as follows: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/61e965eed900355e0dbd27771d6469248d798293/Dapper/project.json . So from my understanding hence I could reference dapper on both my core and .net web apps.

Comment: This isn't true at all. .net 4.5.2 implements netstandard1.2. They are essentially the next iteration of portable class libraries. If I don't need to use features from the full .net framework then I shouldn't need to target it. I can install the netstandard1.2 package into my 4.5.2 application, my only concern is seeing a huge list of dependencies that get added because of this.

Comment: True, _I may be wrong :(_, but I was under the same impression reading their docs that said `.net 4.5.1` implements `netstandard1.2`  here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library and so on., but ran into a similar situation when I created my Lib and uploaded it our ProGet Server to be used across all platforms, and when I added it to .net framework lib , it was trying to download System.Collections etc and took for ever crashing VS, so then did target that framework and uploaded a new pkg, I didnt see the same again, so suggested the same. Am sorry, if am mistaken

Comment: if a library targets netstandard1.2 you can use it in any .net 4.5.1+ apps

Comment: Yup got that wrong,However I did say that one needs to include 452 in the project.json file - please read my answer above ^^ to avoid the dependency downloads or atleast that it did go away in my case